# Why Tomcat shutdowns after startup?

Tags: java, tomcat

I installed tomcat 5 on linux(ubuntu) but after starting it up, it goes down automatically
I checked by this command:

> lsof -i:8080

and it showed the java, but after one second, when i do it again(lsof -i:8080) it showed nothing

---

I checked the logs and saw this:

```
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:336)
at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:336)
at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:202)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:363)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:576)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
```

but no process uses the port 8080, i checked by netstat

Comment: what was the solution and how did you find it?

Comment: @John: I understand that i had another tomcat, which starts automatically on linux startup. I killed that and the problem solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your tomcat bin dir (typically something like : */usr/local/tomcat/bin*) and run:

./catalina.sh run

This will show you output from startup.
One of the issues could be that port your instance of Tomcat was configured to run on has already been taken (try *nestat -an|grep yourportnumber*) to get the list of ports in use.

Comment: I did and wrote the result in question text,but the problem is not solved

Comment: Obviously some process IS using your apache port. But it does not have to be the port 8080, because the file server.xml is defining ports the apps listen on, check this. Also, when starting this way, the tomcat startup should tell you which port is the occupied one.